# How to store anchor id value to a text label and linking to the page with same functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

For example below is the html code for anchor tag

```
<a href="http://google.com" id="t[key]">Text</a>
<input type="text" visibility="hidden" value=" " />
```

Now when I click anchor the id value to store in input field and at the same it should open the google page. How can this can be achieved using Javascript / jQuery?

Comment: It can only store in the input field if you give the link a target - for example `target="_blank"` - have a look at the `on` handler in jQuery and the `onclick` in plain JS. SO needs a bit more effort from your side to answer such questions

Comment: Can you please clarify on your desired output

Answer (score 0):

this should do it:

```js
function doThing(a) {
  $("#inputFieldId").val($(a).html());
  window.open($(a).prop('href'), "_new");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://google.com" onClick="doThing(this)">Text</a>
<input id="inputFieldId" type="text" value=" " />
```